# Export data from Neo4j Sandbox

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, cypher-shell

So i've worked with Neo4j sandbox and i have a whole graph there , but my sandbox is gonna expire so i have to export the data , and import it in my localhost community neo4j instance , i tried to use APOC , but the problem is when i call `apoc.export.cypher.all(.....)` it doesnt work because i have to add `apoc.export.file.enabled=true` in the `neo4j.conf` file in my sandbox instance.

-> Whole error : `Failed to invoke procedure apoc.export.cypher.all : Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Export to files not enabled, please set apoc.export.file.enabled=true in your neo4j.conf`

The problem here is that i can't access the config file on my sandbox , but i can connect to it using `cypher-shell`.

is there any suggestions so that i can export my data before the sandbox expires. Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the data is not consequent ( for eg. the size of the movies database ), you can export to cypher statements to the browser directly by specifying `null` for the `file` option value :

```
CALL apoc.export.cypher.all(null, {format: 'plain'})
YIELD cypherStatements
RETURN cypherStatements
```

Then copy the result ( without the enclosing `"` )

[image]

And paste it in another Neo4j browser, click on the `Run` button, and it's done.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! thats what i needed :D

Answer (score 3):

With the newest Neo4j (4.4.10) it still gives an error on a sandbox instance. `stream:true` fixes the error

It seems

```
CALL apoc.export.cypher.all(null, {format: 'plain', stream:true})
YIELD cypherStatements
RETURN cypherStatements
```